# Selecting a single span in a nested div

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem while optimizing a WebView for mobile devices. It's about making a Search bar visible which is hidden inside a `<p>` of a nested. However, I'm finding no way to select only the span of the Search bar and its label because the other spans in this `<p>` are called practically the same. Whenever I try to do something other than hiding / showing the entire paragraph, nothing works.

It looks something like this

```
<div class="setaction">
<p>
 <span class="nowrap> 
   <span class="labeltext">
    <label for="stxt">Search:
    </label>
   </span>
<input type="text" class="text" size="12" name="stxt" id="stxt" value=""
 onchange="this.form.what.value='srch'; this.form.submit();"/> 
....
</span>
```

So this is the Search label and Search bar that I need, what follows is a (kinda unnecessary) button and a few more options that I don't need to display. They are all inside a `<span class="nowrap">`(there are multiples, one after another) and I'm at a loss about how to only target the few things inside this paragraph that I need.

I would try to select only `stxt`, however when I try to do it via `div.setaction stxt` or any variation of it, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try using id or more class within your element.

Comment: A [paragraph `<p>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) is not for this purpose, you should use a `<div>` instead. By add ing a class/id to your element you're free to style that like `div.setaction #stxt`

Comment: I wish I could edit the website. We are only implementing a webview of a given site, no edits in HTML can be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using attribute selector:

`$("[for='stxt']")`

Which will give you the label.

Comment: Tried implementing this line in Styler, but I saw no results when I tried to make it display as block.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle for the problem because it is working fine for me.

Comment: The site is a personalised e-mail inbox, hidden behind a single sign-on. I'm afraid this makes providing a JSFiddle kinda difficult...

Comment: We are only injecting a css file, nothing we can do about JQuery unfortunately. Otherwise this would have helped greatly!

Comment: Well the thing is inline style have higher order of execution than style in the CSS so unless you remove inline style from html file or update DOM via javascript, it is nearly impossible to tell it'll work without aking look at your html and css files.

Comment: @dschib See this example, https://jsfiddle.net/tctwtstr/1/, but its really a shitty way to achieve what you want

Comment: I understand that. I was able to go about the other way round by hiding everything that is not the search bar. The only thing missing is getting the labels to the corresponding bars hidden as well, but those have no name, are only called `label for="name"`

However, your (albeit hacky) example did the job for me. As it conflicts with nothing else on the website, I can go about it this way. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select `stxt` it appears you are selecting a tag `<stxt></stxt>`. This is obviously not your intent.

Make sure to use `#` or `.` before the selector to select an id or class.

If the element you are selecting does not have an id or class, you can select it by an attribute:

`[attribute=value] /* selects elements whose attribute match the value */`

e.g.
`[for="stxt"]`

If you are trying to select the input, just use `#stxt`

If you are trying to select the label, you can either do:
`[for="stxt"]`, `label` or `.setaction label`

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, as can be seen in the other questions, searching for="stxt" didn't help. The only thing I really can do is display the entire paragraph with the search bar and everything else by using `div.setaction{display: block}`. Everything else either leaves everything at status quo or hides the entire thing again.

The biggest problem is that we can only inject a css file, nothing we can do about JS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select using jquery or CSS?

If you are trying with css, you need to have the class assigned for label too. Here you are using "for" and Css can not select that.

You can also select it in this way.

```
div.setaction label
```

If you are using jquery, you can use "attr".

Comment: I'm only using CSS, as we are injecting the file via a separate backend into the webview inside a mobile app. Does that mean selecting only those things might not be possible with solely CSS?

Comment: I am not sure if you can select "for" using CSS. But if you add class to it, you can. You can also do it by selecting label after setaction. Like this: "div.setaction label "

Comment: Inside the HTML file? We have no access to that.

Comment: If you have no control over HTML code, then you can do it all from CSS. You just need to hit the correct selection. Use the ID or Class if availabe. If not you can use the element like div, lable etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that nobody has said this yet!  CSS has a way built in by default for this very situation.  You should apply the CSS:
`p:first-child{
  CSS here
}`
to select the first option.  More info [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/pseudoelements/) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_firstchild.asp)

Comment: As a matter of fact, this option is used for other things inside the css file, however trying that didn't yield any results. Perhaps I made a mistake somewhere, but I got it working now.